# Refresh RecyclerView fragment from another fragment's adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am making an Android e-commerce app connected to WordPress. In my app I have *two Fragments*: a **Shop fragment** (with products fetched from the website in it) and **My Wishlist fragment** (with wishlist products in it). I also have *two lists*: one for the **retrieved products** and another one for the **wishlist products**. The list of the wishlist products contains every product's index inside the retrieved products list so I can get the full details later (image, description, etc...).

The problem I am facing is when adding products to the wishlist, I want to be able to click the wishlist button in the **Shop fragment** and the wishlist products would show in the **My Wishlist fragment**. I searched a lot online and I found out that I should use `notifyDataSetChanged` but I didn't find any example with how to call it from other Fragments.

If I understand correctly, I should call the `WishlistProductAdapter` from the `ShopProductAdapter` but I'm a beginner in Android development so I'm not sure if I can pull this off by myself.

I believe that this code, which is inside **MyWishlist.java** (fragment), can help:

```
//getting the recyclerview from xml
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.wishlist_products);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.products_column_count), StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

JSONArray shop_products = //fetched from website, done in MainActivity;
ArrayList<String> wishlist_products = ["3","0"]; // It contains product of index 0 and product of index 3 inside shop_products
//initializing the productlist
List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0; i<wishlist_products.size(); i++) {
    String index = wishlist_products.get(i);
    JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) shop_products.get(Integer.parseInt(index));

    productList.add(
            new Product(
                    i,                                            //index
                    Integer.parseInt(JO.get("id").toString()),    //id
                    JO.get("title").toString(),                   //title
                    null,
                    null,
                    JO.get("price").toString(),                   //price
                    JO.get("featured_image_url").toString(),      //image_url
                    null
            )
    );
}
//creating recyclerview adapter
adapter = new WishlistProductAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), productList);

//setting adapter to recyclerview
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

### EDIT:

and **Shop.java** is the same except for the for loop (fragment):

```
for (int i=0; i<shop_products.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) shop_products.get(i);

    productList.add(
        new Product(
            i,
            Integer.parseInt(JO.get("id").toString()),
            JO.get("title").toString(),
            null,
            null,
            JO.get("price").toString(),
            JO.get("featured_image_url").toString(),
            null
        )
    );
}
```

### EDIT:

My code with fragments, adapters and MainActivity is here: https://ufile.io/25z9e

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should provide code for both ShopFragment and WishlistFragment. How these to related? do you have a reference to WishlistFragment inside ShopFragment?

Comment: Added the Shop fragment code. No there's no relation between the two, the wishlist_products are stored inside SharedPreferences. Both fragments are initialized like so:
    `SectionsStatePagerAdapter adapter = new 
    SectionsStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Shop(), "Shop");
    adapter.addFragment(new MyWishlist(), "My Wishlist");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally was able to do show products in My Wishlist fragement after being added from the other fragment inside a List shared by both fragments (using SharedPreferences) using a very simpler solution than the one Kashish suggested.

1. I first added an `onPageSelected` listener inside `MainActivity` like so:

   ```
   mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
       public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
           navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);

           if(position == 0) {
               setSelectedNavItem(0);
               myShop.refreshAdapter();
           } else if (position == 1) {
               setSelectedNavItem(2);
               myWishList.refreshAdapter();
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. Inside each fragment I added a `refreshAdapter()` method like so:

   ```
   public void refreshAdapter() {
       if(productList != null) {
           adapter.productList = productList;
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   }
   ```
3. I globalized `productList` inside each fragment's adapter.

P.S.: Thank you so much [@Kashish Malhotra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6743176/kashish-malhotra) for your help!

Answer (score 4):

The fragments should communicate with each other via the parent Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

Let A be the fragment from which you want to call notifyDataSetChanged() of adapter in fragment B.

So, what you can do is create an interface in the fragment A. Implement this interface in the activity. On the click of the button, call the method of the interface. In the activity, where this interface is implemented, you can get the reference to the fragment B. You can create a method in fragment B in which you can call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

Rough code how to do above -

Create a method in fragment B

```
    public void refreshAdapter(){
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Create an interface in Fragment A

```
   interface RefreshInterface{
            public void refreshAdapterFragmentB();
   }
```

ParentActivity implements RefreshInterface, you need to define the implementation of the refreshAdapterFramgentB() method, and fragmentB is the reference to fragment B which you have in the activity. You can call the refreshAdapter() method of fragment B like this

```
    @Override 
    public void refreshAdapterFragmentB(){
            fragmentB.refreshAdapter();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Kashish for the reply. I'm not sure how to do that, would you mind sharing a small example code on how to get a reference of Fragment B and create a method in it?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: I didn't understand the last paragraph... What should I add inside MainActivity? It already `implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Comment: I added `implements RefreshInterface` but it's throwing an error: { expected

Comment: Ok I had to make Shop.RefreshInterface

Comment: Last code block says: Cannot resolve symbol fragmentB

Comment: Fragment myWishList = new MyWishlist(), myWishList is fragmentB

Comment: `@Override
    public void refreshAdapterFragmentB() {
        Fragment myWIshList = new MyWishlist();
        myWIshList.refreshAdapter();
    }`


This doesn't work, cannot resolve method refreshAdapter()

Comment: And how do I access `myWIshList` inside `refreshAdapterFragmentB()`?

Comment: Declare myWishList as a global variable

Comment: That's what I did... I'm getting `cannot resolve method refreshAdapter()`

Comment: Make refreshAdapter() public

Comment: Oh ok I made it public.. It's the same

Comment: In MyWishList fragment where you have defined this method.

Comment: Inside `public class MyWishlist extends Fragment` after `onViewCreated()`

Comment: If I replace myWishList with new MyWishlist() it doesn't show errors

Comment: I changed `private Fragment myWishList` to `private MyWishlist myWishList ` it works now

Comment: Now how do I call RefreshInterface inside Shop?

Comment: RefreshInterface interface = (RefreshInterface)getActivity(); interface.refreshAdapterFragmentB();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170150/discussion-between-kashish-malhotra-and-toufic-batache).